# Distinct in LINQ sdk

Tags: c#, linq, distinct

I have a LINQ query that basically loads data into an array and then into a listbox; this works well. But what I now want to do is only select distinct. I have done this before in sql, but in linq it does not work for me.

Thanks for any suggestions.

```
items = table
    .Where(row => row.author != "")                    
    .Take(150)
    .ToCollectionView();
```

Comment: Have you tried `Distinct()`? What do you mean “it does not work”? What *does* it do? What is the type of `table`?

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Distinct](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.distinct.aspx) method ...

e.g.

query.Distinct().ToList();

Comment: Hi, how would that look in my code, as when I try to put it In the intellicense does not bring up .tolist() ?

Comment: query.Distinct().ToList();

Comment: James is correct, I missed the parens.  I added them in the edit.

Comment: .Where(row => row.author !="".Distinct().ToList())) It is now coming up with the error that != operands cant be applied to the toList() method call?

Comment: You are missing a paren after "" - e.g.,   .Where(row => row.author !="").Distinct().ToList()

Comment: And keep in mind - the ToList() is not required - I was using it as context to show where Distinct fits in the chain.

Comment: For some reason I cant call the distinct method when I put a paren there, even though it is still in the same query?.Where(row => row.author !="").Distinct().ToList()))